# What is the formula for calculating payment required to pay off a debt on a specific date?

Tags: mortgage

I'm looking for something like `NPER`, but solving for the payment when the number of months is known.

I found [this online calculator](https://www.yourmoneypage.com/home/mortgagepod.php) that does exactly this, but I want a formula that does this so it's easy to work into other calculations.

I'd like to put this into a spreadsheet and I can adapt a formula, I'm just not sure what the formula should be. If there's a standard spreadsheet function that I missed, that will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is that spreadsheet software like Excel has this functionality built-in.

In Excel, you're looking for the `PMT` function, which has the syntax `PMT(rate, nper, pv, [fv], [type])`, where `rate` is the interest rate as a decimal, `nper` is the number of periodic payments, and `pv` is the present value of your debt.

Note that the future value and type arguments are optional.  In your case, future value will be zero (since you want the outstanding balance to be $0 at the end of your number of months).  The type is either 0 or 1 depending on whether payments will be made at the beginning or end of the period (most common is end of period payments, in what is called an ordinary annuity, as opposed to an annuity due).

In application, this means if you type `=pmt(0.01, 6, -1000)` into Excel, you are asking "If I owe $1,000 to a creditor, at a monthly interest rate of 1%, and I want to pay that loan back in 6 months, how much will I have to pay in each monthly installment?"  The answer to this question is $172.55.

If you want a slightly more complicated answer, this can be done mathematically as well.  The formula for the present value of an annuity can be found [on Investopedia here](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/present-value-annuity.asp).

You can easily re-arrange this to solve for `C`, which is the periodic payment, by dividing by the bracketed term on both sides.

Throughout, be very careful that you are matching the frequency of the interest rate to the frequency of payments.  If you have an **annual** interest rate of 18% and are trying to determine your **monthly** payment, you first need to convert the rate to a monthly frequency.  If you know the APR, that is as simple as dividing by 12.

Good luck!